# Likelihood ratio, distribution of test statistic

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, log-likelihood

I want to perform a statistical test given two simple hypothesis. I have the analytical form of my pdf in dependence of $3$ parameters which I know are fixed at $\alpha = 0.65, \beta = 0.06, \gamma = -0.18$ for one hypothesis and $\alpha = 1/3, \beta = 0, \gamma = 0$ for the other hypothesis. For the second hypothesis the pdf reduces to a uniform pdf.

I have a dataset of $50.000$ points sampled from the first distribution (the not uniform one) so the test is trivial but still, I have to do it.

I compute the value of each pdf at every point of the dataset, I take their logarithm and then I subtract them and sum the result to obtain $\log(\lambda)$. Now I find a very low result meaning $\exp(-40772)$ which clearly support the nonuniform distribution of data but how can I compute the significance region or the power of the test? I cannot use Wilk's theorem since my pdf is completely defined. The only thing I can do is the following:

$P(\lambda < c | H_0) = \alpha$

But I do not know how to compute $c$. Has anyone suggestions?

For clarity I will post the two pdfs:

Variables $\theta, \phi$ defined in $\theta \in [0, \pi], \phi \in [0, 2\pi]$.

$$ (,)=34[0.5(1−)+(0.5)(3−1)()^{2}−()^2(2)−\sqrt{2}\gamma(2)()] $$

$$\alpha = 0.65, \beta = 0.06, \gamma = -0.18 $$

Uniform pdf:
$$ U(\theta, \phi) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}} & \theta \in [0, \pi], \phi \in [0, 2\pi]\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases} $$

Comment: You might want to double check for typos in your $F(\theta, \phi)$. In particular, why is there a $2$ following $\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: Thank you veri much @LeeDavidChungLin , corrected it.